# How to create inset shadow for a View in react-native - iOS, Android?

Tags: react-native, shadow

Is there a way to create a inset shadow for a view in react native ?

Comment: Same snack link https://snack.expo.io/BJSQJt36Z

Comment: I'm looking exactly for the same, did you find a solution? most of the shadows generated are outside the element, I want the shadow to be rendered inside of the container

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
containerStyle: {
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderRadius: 2,
  borderColor: '#ddd',
  borderBottomWidth: 0,
  shadowColor: '#000',
  shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
  shadowOpacity: 0.8,
  shadowRadius: 2,
  elevation: 1,
  marginLeft: 5,
  marginRight: 5,
  marginTop: 10,
}
})
```

Comment: Not sure. If I did anything wrong. But for some reasons I was not able to create a inner shadow on UIView with the above mentioned code snippet.

Comment: @DhananjayPuglia update your post with tried code. So that others can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearGradient
  style={styles.gradientButton}
  colors={['#040406', '#040406', '#040406', '#444446']}
  start={{ x: 0.48, y: 0.1 }}
  end={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.6 }}
>
```

**I am using expo linear gradient, keep backgrund "#777" for better look**